# Single vSwitch, multiple physical NICs, no way to team - is this possible?

Tags: hyper-v, vswitch

I have two Hyper-V hosts connected to a single* ASA5505 appliance that does switching and routing for them and various VMs on those hypervisors. Now, as the traffic increases, the ASA became the bottleneck as it only has 100mbit/s ports, and we have already used two per server to make a team. I am considering adding adapters to the hosts and connecting them directly in order to provide VM local network interconnectivity at 1Gbps speed (or better, if teamed). The problem is, we have no space left to install a switch, and with current setup and my knowledge, I am not able to have two NICs bridged on a host level (that is, packets arriving to one NIC will not leave from the other one if destined to a different IP address than the host's or VMs' addresses). I wonder if bridging can be performed on a vSwitch level, after all, it already can switch packets.

What should I do to make Hyper-V vSwitch or the host itself to act as a bridge between two specific NIC adapters? OS is Windows Server 2012R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer to your question.

No, you cant add multiple network adaptors to a single vSwitch, you can only add a single adapter or team/bonded group.

Ok, I had similar issue to you not so long ago, I had two hosts in a Development office that transferred a lot of data between them, I think from reading your post you are having a similar issue, both IBM machines, but I only had two floor ports

So I installed an Intel 4 port Gbps adaptor in each, connected 4 cables between the two and teamed(bonded) them together, then connected each teamed NIC group to a virtual switch giving plenty of connectivity between them.

I then used pfsense connected to one of on-board NICs and the vswitch of the teamed NICs to provide access back to the main network, my hosts also had separate connection back to the switch for management and backups.